# Overriding CompareTo using Equal method

Tags: java

I am trying to read in a vector of companies and returns true if two companies have the same name, false otherwise Which I have done using ComapareTo method. In my method that will call the “equals” method in the class Company. My “equals” method must override the corresponding method in the class Object.

What I want to know is it possible to override CompareTo using an Equal method. If so how can I check it in main.

The objective of this program is to check the 2 companies in a vector if so return true else false. Here is the code I am stuck in main to test it.

```
public class Company implements Comparable <Company> {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private String cName;



public String getName()
{
    return cName;
}

public int compareTo(Company b)
{
    if(this.cName == b.cName)
    {
        System.out.println(" from compareTo true");
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println(" from compareTo false");
        return 0;
    }
}

public boolean equal(Object o)
{
    if (o instanceof Company)
    {
        Company c = (Company) o;
        if(this.cName.equals(c.cName))
        {
            System.out.println(" from equal true");
                return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" from equal false");
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();

    Company obj1 = new Company();
    Company obj2 = new Company();

    v.add("Rio tinto");
    v.add("BHP");
    v.add("BHP");
    v.add("CBA");

    Collections.sort(v);

    System.out.println(v);

}
```

The code is bit tangled pardon me for that was just trying different approaches.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how `compareTo()` works.  If two objects are equal you should return `0`.

Comment: In addition to the other bad things, you are comparing two strings using `==`.  This is wrong under normal circumstances, and your example probably qualifies as "normal circumstances".

Answer (score 5):

The contract for `compareTo` according to [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) indicates this:

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is **transitive**: (x.compareTo(y)>0 && > y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0.

So the answer to your question is - no, you cannot. In your case:
`compare("A","B") == 1` and `compare("B","A") == 1` which means that `"A"<"B"` and `"B"<"A"` which is naturally not true nor transitive.

If you want to save time - implement `compareTo` and use it inside `equals`.
Something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    // ... Some stuff you need to complete here first
    return this.compareTo(o) == 0;
}
```

Naturally `compareTo` will expect an object of type `Company` - so you will have to verify that before sending it to `compareTo`

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend against this approach. The `compareTo` method is expected to return an integer that indicates the relative ordering of the objects. The contract specifies (in part) that `a.compareTo(b)` returns `0` exactly when `a.equals(b)` returns `true`. However, when `a.equals(b)` returns `false`, then `a.compareTo(b)` and `b.compareTo(a)` should return non-zero integers *of opposite sign*. Your implementation does not do that.

Comment: @ Ted compareTo is used to compare against own class objects ist it? So what I am trying to do is do is to check cName is equal to is own name Object. This way I can check if Vector have any smiler Company name. If this isnt the way of implementing to check the compareTo how would u do it?

Comment: Just use `equals` to check whether the vector already contains a company with the same name; it already tells you what you want to know. Why bother trying to make `compareTo` do the job that `equals` already does?

Answer (score 0):

first off using == to check for equality of objects should never be done; replace it with

```
if(this.cName.equals(b.cName)){
```

for compareTo you can simply return the compareTo of the strings

```
public int compareTo(Company b)
{
    return this.cName.compareTo(b.cName);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit too strong to say that using `==` "should never be done". It's true that `==` checks object _identity_, which is often not the same as object _equality_. However, it can be a first step in a test for equality (to short-circuit more expensive testing in the case of an object being tested against itself) or (like with `Object.equals`) as the complete definition of equality.